# How can i change the degree at which the gradient starts

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient, layer, angle

i'm using this repository to draw a gradient,

https://github.com/paiv/AngleGradientLayer/blob/master/AngleGradient/AngleGradientLayer.m

I'm trying to get the angle at which the gradients start, to change.

The gradient on the left is what i have currently, and on the right what I'm trying to achieve.

http://i.imgur.com/muUPD0U.png

I need to manage to edit the code, I got the result i wanted on the right by making the layer bigger and rotating it but it means drawing more pixels on screen, which is not efficient.

Thanks in advance.

```
AngleGradientLayer *l = (AngleGradientLayer *)self.layer;

l.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:38.0 / 255.0 green:154.0 / 255.0 blue:151.0 / 255.0 alpha:1].CGColor,
            (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:231.0 / 255.0 green:210.0 / 255.0 blue:130.0 / 255.0 alpha:1].CGColor,
            (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:195.0 / 255.0 green:85.0 / 255.0 blue:82.0 / 255.0 alpha:1].CGColor,
            nil];


NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

self.value1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(0.0)];
self.value2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(0.5)];
self.value3 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1.0)];

[locations addObject: self.value1];
[locations addObject: self.value2];
[locations addObject: self.value3];

l.locations = locations;
```

Comment: The "values" wind up corresponding to the location of the color stops in the gradient (beginning, 50%, and 100%). Experiment with changing them & see what the effect is. For example change from 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 to something like 0.0, 0.3, 0.6.

Comment: I have already tried everything i can think of, nothing affects that line if you refer to the image. The color spread works great, but that is not what i'm trying to change.

Comment: Yeah, that is weird. The only angle I see in the code is calculated with each row/column as the gradient is built, based on the width & height of the CGRect - it's not a parameter you can control directly. Did you try not starting @ 0.0? Make the 1st location 0.3 & see if you make the last one 1.3? Looks like you prob can't use negative values, but maybe greater than 1.0 works?

Comment: Yes, just tried that but it doesn't change the start point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code I've patched into the `angleGradient(...)` function in AngleGradientLayer.m.

```
float offset = M_PI / 4;
float angle = atan2f(dirY, dirX) + offset;
while (angle < 0) angle += 2 * M_PI;
while (angle > 2 * M_PI) angle -= 2 * M_PI;
while (angle < 0) angle += 2 * M_PI;
```

It replaces these lines

```
    float angle = atan2f(dirY, dirX);
    if (dirY < 0) angle += 2 * M_PI;
```

Typically, you want to make offset a parameter of the function and a property of `AngleGradientLayer`. `offset` is in radiants (0 ... 2π). You can go with -offset if you want to shift following counter-clockwise logic.

Comment: I am already using it, if you look at the image i posted, that doesn't affect the line where the first color starts.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot guess your code. You should show it.

Comment: It's like in the example, the locations property affect the way the colors are spread, i'm trying to change the line you see on the left to appear like the one on the right.

Comment: Those numbers have a meaning. Your code starts at 0.0. If you want it to be different, use different numbers!

Comment: I know, but this has nothing to do with what i'm trying to achieve, this changes the color spread, not the actual start point of the gradient, please look at the image and you should understand what i mean.

Comment: I must apologize, the locations really didn't fit the bill. Please find my changes to the given code (tested) above.